# How to assign the TEXT (not the VALUE) from a SELECT OPTION into a variable using Coldfusion 8?

Tags: javascript, variables, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

The question here is not how I can retrieve the TEXT but how I can assign the TEXT string to a ColdFusion variable!
I need this:

```
 <cfset myVariable = "the selected TEXT from my HTML SELECT control">
```

Here is what I tried:

```
<cfif IsDefined("Form.formCommand")>
    <cfif Form.formCommand eq "save">
    ...

        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('hiddenManufacturerName').value = GetTextFromSelect('manufacturerId');
        </script>">

        <cfset ManufacturerName = Form.hiddenManufacturerName>
        <cfdump var="#ManufacturerName#"><br>
        <cfabort>...


            function GetTextFromSelect(selectElementId)
            {
                var objSelect = document.getElementById(selectElementId);
                var theText = "";
                if (objSelect.selectedIndex != -1)
                {
                    theText = objSelect.options[objSelect.selectedIndex].text;
                }
                return theText;
            }
```

When I dump the variable above I get an empty string.

On a side note:
I did found a solution where you would add the TEXT in the value attribute and then retrieve it, for instance, instead of

```
<option value="1">Manufacturer IBM</option>
```

do the following:

```
<option value="1, Manufacturer IBM">Manufacturer IBM</option>
```

I do NOT want to go that route or take this approach.
There must be a way to do this.

Thank you

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the chain of events. CF executes on the server **first**. By the time any javascript code runs, the CF code is long finished. If you want to grab the list text, you must run the javascript code (to save the text in a form field) **before** submitting the form.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the effective approach that you discovered?

Comment: Huh? Invoking javascript code **after** the form is submitted is not going to populate a CF FORM variable in the next line. [ColdFusion Request/Response Process](http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2012/10/the-coldfusion-requestresponse-process.html)

Comment: The effective approach does not involve javascript.

Comment: Oh, you mean the combined value/text approach :/ Phew. You scared me for minute ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you trying to pre-select a pulldown menu:

```
<select name="ManufacturerName">

<cfoutput query="qryManufacturer">
  <option value="#ManufacturerID#">
       <cfif ManufacturerID EQ form.ManufacturerID>selected</cfif>
     #ManufacturerName#</option> 
</cfoutput>

</select>
```

Comment: No, the question is: "how I can assign the TEXT string to a ColdFusion variable!"

Comment: James, I have a HTML Select control called 'manufacturerId' and I am trying to get the TEXT of the selected value after I submit the form. I am not a ColdFusion developer so the ColdFusion syntax is rather new to me. Now with your answer, it points me to the right direction; I will check what the SELECT tag does in the Adobe site. I did not quite understand the syntax above. I know you are looping through all values and checking if they are selected, it is just weird...the syntax I mean - thanks

Comment: @Max - This really has nothing to do with ColdFusion. CF merely displays whatever you submitted via method=POST. `<select>` is an HTML element and its behavior is dictated by the [HTML specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6), not the Adobe docs. According the specs, only the list `value` is submitted, not the text. If you want to submit the `text`, you must store that in a separate element **before** the form is submitted. Then it will be accessible in a CF `FORM` variable.

Comment: Leigh, I didn't misunderstood the sequence of events, I am just tired. I have my .Net projects and now am helping doing maintanence in a ColdFusion project because the employee left the company...anyways, I was storing the value in a hidden field before the POST. I was doing it via OnChange event for the select HTML control...cant remember why I removed it... thanks for putting me back on track...I will retrieve the values from Form fields, the hidden ones -- Thanks

Comment: @Max - Ah, okay. We have all been there. Sorry to repeat stuff you already know .. but sounds like it worked out in the end :)

Comment: Max - When you get a chance, you should either post the actual resolution as an "answer" - or you could delete the thread as "highly localized".